# How to multiply seperate cells in excel 2016?

Tags: excel-formula

I am doing a Controlled assessment, and I'm trying to multiply 2 seperate cells to get a value. I tried `=g2*e2`, but it says `#VALUE!`, can anyone help me please?

A screenshot is available [image: here.]

Comment: From your screenshot it shows `G2` value is not a `Number`. It is a text field. So, how you would multiply a text field?

Comment: @harun24hr Thanks, I changed it and it is indeed working, I wondered if the m2 was playing up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol mate, you need to make it a number value, like harun24hr said.